# Geolocation redirect (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to make script that will redirect user depending on location. I programmed this script and geolocating works but redirecting doesn't. Why can't I redirect user?

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
    }
    function showError(error)
      {
      switch(error.code)
        {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.")
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          alert("Location information is unavailable.")
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          alert("The request to get user location timed out.")
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          alert("An unknown error occurred.")
          break;
        }
      }


    if (pos.coords.longitude >= 45.775534 && pos.coords.longitude <= 45.775562 && pos.coords.latitude <= 15.994809 && pos.coords.latitude >= 15.994792)
        {window.location = 'success.html';
        }
        else{
            window.location = 'other.html';
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question: [HTML5 geolocation redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781759/html5-geolocation-redirect). If a question gets closed, then edit it so it could be reopened. Don't ask it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code |pos| is not defined, you will need to define the function showPosition()

```
function showPosition(pos)
  {

   if (pos.coords.longitude >= 45.775534 && pos.coords.longitude <= 45.775562 && pos.coords.latitude <= 15.994809 && pos.coords.latitude >= 15.994792)
        {
            window.location = 'success.html';
        }
        else{
            window.location = 'other.html';
        }
  }
```

Also I noticed that on Chrome, for a local file, the Geolocation does not seem to work, hence I have created a JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/PXp9y/ and made use of alert() instead of window.location. Check it out.